# Credit Card processing library that handles many merchant gateways?

Tags: c#, .net, e-commerce, credit-card

Looking for a c# library that interfaces to multiple merchant gateways.
Should at minimum be able to handle PayPal and authorize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [dotnetcharge](http://www.dotnetcharge.com/) with success.  They have support for something like 50 payment processors, plus (most importantly), data storage encryption for credit card information.

Comment: IMHO - I would not recommend dotnetcharge. I found their product to be sub standard, support rude and documentation poor.

Comment: With the more I'd used dotnetcharge, I agree with you. They used to be good, but have gone downhill.  There are much better solutions out there now (2 years later)

Comment: could you please name some of them?  I'm investigating this area at the moment & would appreciate some war stories / recommendations :-)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that working with the gateways themselves is extremely simple, Adding support to your application for each one shouldn't be difficult.

That said, here is one that claims to have the support you want:

http://www.componentsource.com/products/ibiz-e-payment-integrator-net/index.html

Note that Payflow link and payflow pro were purchased by PayPal from verisign.